# PHP unable to retrieve data from jQuery's serialize()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to send an e-mail with contact information through Wordpress's native PHPMailer class and Ajax. Here's the relevant code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#formContato').submit(ajaxSubmit);

  function ajaxSubmit() {
    var newCustomerForm = jQuery('#formContato').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: {
        action: 'sendmail',
        newCustomerForm
      },
      success: function(data) {

        jQuery("#alertaOk").show();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(newCustomerForm);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown) {

        jQuery("#alertaErro").show();
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
#alertaOk {
  display: none;
}

#alertaErro {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="formContato" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Mensagem" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-left btn-laranja" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="alertaOk" class="alert alert-success">
    <strong>Obrigado!</strong> Recebemos sua mensagem e entraremos em contato em breve.
  </div>
  <div id="alertaErro" class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Algo deu errado.</strong> Nossos administradores já foram avisados, por favor envie sua mensagem para o e-mail <a href="contato@empresa.com.br">contato@empresa.com.br</a> .
  </div>
</form>
```

The Ajax sends the data to a function in Wordpress's functions.php file that calls PHPMailer. Before initializing PHPMailer I'm retrieving the ajax data like this:

```
$nome = trim($_POST['name']);
$mensagem = trim($_POST['comments']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
```

and then trying to print it into the email's body:

```
    $mail->Body = "Nome: " . $nome . "\nE-mail: " . $email . "\nMensagem: " . $mensagem;
```

PHP executes the functions just right, I receive the test emails, but it's not receiving the data from the Ajax call. The console is showing the serialized data, which means that it's not wrong, but somehow it's not reaching the PHP script. I suspect it's something related to Wordpress.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't you have to name the serialized data? action: 'sendmail',newCustomerForm:newCustomerForm

Comment: @FunkDoc no... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `newCustomerForm` needs to have a key in `data`:

```
data: {
   action: 'sendmail',
   custForm: newCustomerForm
}
```

And in your PHP file you will need to parse the `custForm` string:

```
parse_str($_POST['custForm'], $form);
//Then access the custForm data using $form, e.g. $form['name']
```

Comment: you're on the money with `parse_str`, however the `data:` object was fine as written, he doesn't need to give `newCustomerForm` a key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass two different type of 'parameters' at the same time, either you pass the serialized data or you pass it by each element.  Put the action into the `newCustomerForm` before you serialize it. 
So

```
 data: {
    action: 'sendmail',
    newCustomerForm
  },
```

is

```
 data: newCustomerForm,
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you can have many parameters.The only problem is that `newCustomerForm` doesn't have a key. As @Funk Doc commented.

Comment: newCustomerForm is an serialized array, so wouldn't need a key.  But he's trying to mix a single entry with an array and address it as an array.  He needs to change either the way he passes the data or change the php on how he reads it.  I went for the Javascript way.